# Python Subprocess: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, subprocess, wget

**Overview**: I am trying to use the Python subprocess module to execute complex wget commands. I am using Python because I can randomly switch between HTTP header values for each job, better organize results, etc. I like wget instead of the similar Python packages because I know wget quite well and prefer it. I also like how easy it is to route the job through the Tor relay via torsocks. For reference, I am an Ubuntu user. I really appreciate the assistance.

**Problem**: having little experience in the subprocess module, I've spent a lot of time on Python.org and Stackoverflow to learn how to correctly employ subprocess. However, I can't seem to connect what I've learned there to a solution for my problem. In some cases, Python will create the time-date stamped results directory correctly, but I'll then find the results in some other place, like the pwd. In other cases, directory creation works, but the wget functions seem to fail. When I looked at the wget logfile, the error I saw pop up from time to time was "Scheme missing." This error may be tied to directory creation.

**Relevant code**:

```
targetURL="https://www.wikipedia.org"
targethost="Wikipedia"
# the general wget results folder
root_dir='/home/me/Documents/wget/'
# the exact results folder based on the target URL and date/time
results_dir=root_dir+targethost+"/"+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
if not os.path.exists(results_dir):
    os.makedirs(results_dir)

# args is a list of all wget variables
subprocess.call(args, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, timeout=None)
```

**Example values from the args variable pushed to subprocess**:

```
['torsocks', 'wget', '-w 300', '--random-wait', '-e robots=off', '--append-output', '--directory-prefix=/home/me/Documents/wget/Wikipedia/2017-12-09', "--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36'", "--header='Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5'", "--header='Accept-Language: en-ZA,en;q=0.5'", "--header='Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5, *;q=0'", "--referer='https://www.google.com/'", "--header='Connection: keep-alive'", '-p', '-k', '-m', 'https://www.wikipedia.org/']
```

Comment: You don't need subprocess or wget for this--you can simply use `requests.get()` with the `proxies` parameter to go via Tor.  See here: https://gist.github.com/jefftriplett/9748036

Comment: Hello. Thank you. My understanding is that requests cannot do recursive downloading. And, my primary purpose for asking about subprocess is because I want to better understand subprocess more broadly.